compare 2 arrays with different sets of elements and get the difference
I have 2 arrays similar to below structure. I want to compare each field and then store the array item which has a difference into a third array.
Arr1= [{ state:CA, id:1, name:aaa, product:car, color: white}, {...}] 

and so on
Arr2= [{ id:1, name:bbb, product:car, color: white, mileage:30, type: sedan}, {...}] 

and so on
Arr3= [{ state: CA, id:1, name:aaa, product:car, color: white}], 

Error/result/difference = name(something like this)
Intention is to combine id,make,product,color and treat it as a key field to compare with second array, If there is difference of value in one of these fields, get the entire object into third array.
Note: These two arrays have different sets of keys, value pairs(only few which are common), I want to compare these common items of each object in arr1 with each object of arr2, and point out the difference
Note#2: I dont want to see array object's which are missing in one another, my focus is one the ones which match each other and perhaps one key value(out of few common keys) that do not match.
The suggested answer donot match my question.
Hope I was able to explain it.

Those aren't arrays, you need [] around arrays.

Thats true, Arr1=[ { state:CA, id:1, name:aaa, product:car, color: white}, {...}]

@Barmar I dont want to see array object's which are missing in one another, my focus is one the ones which match each other and perhaps one key value(out of few common keys) that do not match.
The suggested answer donot match my question.

I've reopened, but it seems like it should be simple to adapt the code to what you want. Please show what you tried and we'll help you fix it, we won't write it for you.

Change the filter to look for objects that have the same ID but are different in other properties.

I am not very sure If understood some parts of the question, for example
why didn't type: sedan make it to arr3, however from what I understood this code should fit your needs
const arr1 = [
    { state: "CA", id: 1, name: "aaa", product: "car", color: "white" },
    { state: "NY", id: 2, name: "ccc", product: "bike", color: "red" },
  ];

  const arr2 = [
    { id: 1, name: "bbb", product: "car", color: "white", mileage: 30, type: "sedan" },
    { id: 2, name: "ddd", product: "bike", color: "blue", mileage: 15, type: "mountain" },
  ];

  const compare = (arr1, arr2) => {
    const result = [];

    arr1.forEach((item1, index1) => {
      const item2 = arr2.find((item2) => item1.id === item2.id);
      if (!item2) return;

      const keys1 = Object.keys(item1);
      const keys2 = Object.keys(item2);
      const commonKeys = keys1.filter(key => keys2.includes(key));

      let anyMismatch = false;

      commonKeys.forEach((key) => {
        if (item1[key] !== item2[key]) {
          anyMismatch = true;
        }
      });

      // If there is any mismatch in common keys, add the entire object from arr1 along with its index
      if (anyMismatch) {
        result.push({ ...item1, index: index1 });
      }
    });

    return result;
  };

  console.log(compare(arr1, arr2));



I am so close to it, the above code gets the all the other keys(columns) and puts it in 3rd array in case there is a match, whereas George what I want is in case any of the common columns that do not match but the others match, entire array object whether from(arr1,arr2 doesnt matter) & index if possible(if we put it in a for loop?) to be put in 3rd array.

Let me explain, in the above example , note id, product, color of 1st index matches with 1st index of arr2, but name dont match(from the same index). I want this entire object (whether from arr1,arr2 doesnt matter)  or index from arr1(whichever is easier) to be put in 3rd array. Hope i was able to explain.

i edited the answer according to this, but i would suggest you do not directly use it but see the methods or logic you want and try to write it yourself for a better outcome

Thanks, this helps. I changed the script little bit to suit my requirement.
